# Matching in Bipartite Graphs - Saturation

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I have the following question in my homework and I'm not sure how to go about proving it. Hall's Theorem states that the graph contains a matching saturating X is and only if |N(S)| >= |S| for all S _( X. First of all in this question it says that the first part is only greater and the second part is strictly a subset. Am I correct in interpreting the following: Since S is a non-empty subset of X, and N(S) > S for all S, doesn't that mean that every vertex in X has at least 2 edges going to Y? Because I could make S any single vertex and then I would have N(S) > S so there must be more than one edge going from X to Y right? If this is true, how does this help me make my proof?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct, but I'm not sure if it is useful.

Take your graph and pick some edge $e \in E$. Then remove $e$ along with the two vertices it connects. Look for a matching in this new graph. Do you see a connection between a matching in this new graph and a matching in the original graph? Can you conclude that $e$ belongs to some matching of the original graph?

Comment: If we remove an edge along with the two vertices it connects, we could be removing multiple edges, because if we remove the vertices, any other edges connected to them would also have to be removed. Is that what you mean? Ot do you just mean the single edge but keep the vertices?

Comment: That is what I mean. It is very well possible that multiple edges will be removed! But that is not an issue.

Say $e$ connects $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. If we remove $e$,$x$,$y$, and all of the edges connected to $x$ or $y$, we are left with a new graph $G'$. Now take some $S \subseteq X - \{x\}$ in $G'$. Then compare $N(S)$ in $G'$ to $N(S)$ in $G$. Do you see why $|N(S)|$ in $G'$ is either equal to or one less than $|N(S)|$ in $G$?

Comment: Yes, of course, because there may have been edges in vertices that were not x that went to y, but now that y is removed, those edges that did go to y are also removed, so |N(S)| decreases by that number. But I don't see how that helps me with that the question is asking.

Comment: $|N(S)|$ will decrease by at most one since the only vertex that can be removed from $N(S)$ is $y$.

Now since $|N(S)| > |S|$ in $G$, we have $|N(S)| \geq |S|$ in $G'$, so Hall's Theorem gives us a matching in $G'$. Now if we take this matching and add $e$ to it, we get a matching in $G$ containing $e$.

Comment: How do you know that |N(S)| >= |S| in G'? All we proved was that |N(S)| in G >= |N(S)| in G'.

Comment: $|N(S)|$ in $G'$ can only be one less than $|N(S)|$ in $G$ since $y$ is the only vertex that can possibly be removed. All of the other vertices in $N(S)$ connect to some vertex in $S$, i.e. they were not connected to $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120399/discussion-between-a-boy-and-jlinsta).